# How to create a new panel section in Visual Studio Code using extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How can I create a panel section like the one that Gitlens has (see the screenshot below)? I've looked over the documentation and the Github examples presented [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples) and I could not find anything on how to create this.

I want to have a button there next to TERMINAL and when I press on it to present a webview.

[image]

Comment: have you searched the gitlens source code for the tab title text

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do this by creating a viewContainer in the `contributes` object.

```
"viewsContainers": {
            "panel": [
                {
                    "id": "myPanel",
                    "title": "Colors",
                    "icon": "images/views/history.svg"
                }
            ]
        },
```

and then I create a view that uses the viewContainer.

```
    "contributes": {
        "views": {
            "myPanel": [
                {
                    "type": "webview",
                    "id": "calicoColors.colorsView",
                    "name": "Calico Colors"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: For anyone looking for the reference of the example above, here's the link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/webview-view-sample